# splitting string issue: neither using preg_split nor expode() works

Tags: php, regex

I have this string being passed through

`linktest>http://1.com/`

as $value.

`$fixed = preg_split("/>/", $value);`

is ran and when i run the print_r function on $fixed it returns like this

`Array ( [0] => linktest>http://1.com/ )`

What I'm trying to do is separate the string by the angled bracket (>) which my expected yield would be

```
Array ( [0] => linktest, [1] => http://1.com/ )
```

Earlier in my script I run a similiar function like this

```
preg_split("/[\s]+/"), $string);
```

Which seperates by the character space and returns everything that was between the spaces. I don't understand why the above, isn't being separated but I've tested my regex and it works on selecting the angled bracket.

Comment: This is giving expected output https://eval.in/457524. Isn't it???

Comment: [Its working fine for me](https://eval.in/457525)

Comment: It woks for me... no need escape the angle bracket

Comment: @Manwal Yeah I understand the function clearly, I don't think the error is the code itself but something to do with the enviroment. If I run the exact same code snippet anywhere else it works.

Comment: Why don't you use `explode()`  or `str_split()` instead

Comment: I ran my function like this `$fixed = explode(">", $value);
   trigger_error(var_dump($value));
   trigger_error(var_dump($fixed));`
And My Result Was
`string(25) "linktest>http://1.com/" `
`array(1) { [0]=> string(25) "linktest>http://1.com/" } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the following snippet and it works, you may have other problems in your code:

```
$value = "something>again>thisisgood";

print_r(preg_split("/\>/", $value));
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => something [1] => again [2] => thisisgood )
```

A Side Note:

Why aren't you using `explode()` function? which returns an array of your string split by a delimiter specified through parameter, which in your case is:

```
explode(">", $value);
```

And it returns an array of string separated by ">".

**Update:**

As talked through comments, ">" is encoded as an HTML entity and hence it should be treated as an HTML entity in your delimiter, too.

```
explode("&gt;", $value);
```

Comment: `>` is not [Metacharacter](https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php) you don't have to escape it with `\`.

Comment: I tried escaping the angled bracket, it did not work. I was using explode before I tried using preg_split instead. Using explode, exactly as you did it did not work.

Here I tried using


`print_r(preg_split("/\>/", $value));`


and my result was still


`Array ( [0] => linktest>http://1.com/ ) `

Comment: Are you sure about the value of `$value` ? Please `var_dump()` it and then put the result here.

Comment: Please try this and report the result: `explode("&#62;", $value);` Just to make sure that `>` is not encoded as an HTML entity.

Comment: I'm getting this output
`array(1) { [0]=> string(25) "linktest>http://1.com/" } `

Comment: Also Interesting, If I run `explode("&gt;", $value);` I get `array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "linktest" [1]=> string(16) "http://1.com/" } `

Actually that fixed it

Comment: Then it was encoded as HTML. I'll added it to my answer